# Single Page Navigation Menu Dynamically Generated

Tags: wordpress

hHi all! I have posted this question on the WP support forums, but the community doesn't seem to be as active as stack's, so I am taking a chance here!

I am looking for a plugin that would automatically create a navigation menu (through the use of shortcodes for example) on a long single page documentation page.
The long page is divided into sections. I can imagine using a shortcode at the beginning of every section, and this will create a menu that would be displayed in a sidebar for example (called through a second shortcode perhaps, or a widget)

Any thoughts? Advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the answer provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[section]Section Title[/section]` shortcodes, then `[section_navigation]` where you want the navigation links output.

This works, but with a **massive** caveat -- that `[section_navigation]` needs to be in your post/page **after** the other `[section]` shortcodes... otherwise it generates an empty list.

You should be ok to use it in your theme by putting `<?php echo do_shortcode("[section_navigation]");?>` in sidebar.php. It will work as long as `get_sidebar()` is after `the_content()` in your theme templates (it usually is).

*This to go in functions.php*

```
$whit_sections = "";

// [section]My Section Title[/section]                                          
function whit_section_shortcode( $atts, $title = null ) {
    // $content is the title you have between your [section] and [/section] 

    $id = urlencode(strip_tags($title)); 
    // strip_tags removes any formatting (like <em> etc) from the title.
    // Then urlencode replaces spaces and so on.

    global $whit_sections;
    $whit_sections .= '<li><a href="#'.$id.'">'.$title.'</a></li>';

    return '<span id="'.$id.'">'.$title.'</span>';

}
add_shortcode('section', 'whit_section_shortcode');


// [section_navigation]
function whit_section_navigation_shortcode( $atts, $title = null ) {

    global $whit_sections;
    return '<ul class="section-navigation">'.$whit_sections.'</ul>';

}
add_shortcode('section_navigation', 'whit_section_navigation_shortcode');
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it out, although I've hard coded it for now, but will come in handy later on. I will let you know if it works as advertised ;)  Thanks so much for your help and your time!

Comment: I think you should wrap this thing in a nice little plugin, I am sure there are a lot of people looking for this out there! Nice work.