# Default WordPress navigation for single page theme

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, permalinks

I have found a similar question here: [Single Page Navigation Menu Dynamically Generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856712/single-page-navigation-menu-dynamically-generated) but I am not too sure how or even if this will work with what I am doing.

I am building a single page theme, in which every time the user creates a new page a new `<section id="page-title"></section>` is created and filled with the supplied content. I have all that working fine, but I am trying to use WordPress's default navigation. As in when a user creates a new page, it automatically gets added to the nav menu. Right now I have that working of course, but the links point to the page permalinks which I do not want. I need the page to point to a url like '**/#page-title**'

How can I adjust the wordpress `wp_nav_menu();` function to display the # hashtag and the page title for the navigation instead of the permalink?

Comment: Instead of adding the page in the wordpress menu, you could utilize the Custom Link which you can specify the URL that you want for the menu.

Comment: How do I utilize that feature?

Comment: In wordpress, go to Apperance -> Menus. On the left right above your pages that you can bring in, there is a Custom Links box. You can use that.

Comment: That won't work for this. I want to use the wordpress menu...

Comment: That is the wordpress menu. It behaves the exact same way as adding a page. You add a custom link to your menu and it shows up in your assigned menu for wp_nav_menu().